# X Macro generate stray operator

Tags: c++, macros

I try to create a macro to define X, but 08 and 09 are misinterpreted by the compiler as a stray operator. Why do these fail when the others work fine?

```
#define LIST_TEST_X \
    X(A,01)\
    X(B,02)\
    X(C,03)\
    X(D,04)\
    X(E,05)\
    X(F,06)\
    X(G,07)\
    X(H,08)\
    X(I,09)\
    X(K,10)

enum XEnum
{
#define X(A, b)  A=b,
    LIST_TEST_X
#undef X
};
```

Comment: If you look at the output from clang, it will tell you the exact problem: https://godbolt.org/g/WrphQz - error: invalid digit '8' in octal constant
    LIST_TEST_X

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Integer constants that start with a `0` are octal constants.  Since `8` and `9` are not valid digits, `08` and `09` will not compile.

Either remove the leading zeroes on your constants, or replace them with spaces.

Comment: Thanks. Spaces is the choice. The code will look a bit nicer.